# ActiveX Textbox linked cell returning text instead of number

Tags: excel, textbox

I have created an activeX textbox and through its properties I have set the Linked cell value to E12.  When I type a number in E12, the number shows up in the textbox.  When I type a number in the textbox, the number is place in E12 formatted as text.  Is there a way to get the value placed in E12 as a number without using VBA? Is there a better way to achieve getting the number placed in a textbox entered into a cell as a number and have the dynamic link between the two work both ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no VBA-less solution to force the data from the text box into the linked cell as a number, but you could employ a second cell to get what you need:

```
| Linked   Cell | Numeric Cell |
|---------------|--------------|
| 30.1          | =VALUE(A12)  |
```

This maintains your two-way link between the linked cell and your text box, and still gives you a fixed location for the numeric form of your input.

You may also want to add some sort of error handling within the numeric cell if you don't want to have #Value! errors when the text box is blank or contains other characters that can't convert to a number.

Comment: yeah I figured I could do a clean, trim, *1, type operation to convert it to a number in a separate cell, but I was trying to avoid the extra cell sitting off somewhere.